# MVEL expression with Numeric keys

Tags: java, expression, mvel

We are using MVEL to evaluate the expression by passing the map in the context object. The map contains SNMP trap information such as OID and its values. e.g. sample Map contains following Keys and values.

```
    Map<String,String> trapMap = new HashMap();
    trapMap.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.3", "(7362915) 20:27:09.15");
    trapMap.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.2", "2.2");
    trapMap.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19", "0");
    trapMap.put("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.16", "SIMPLE TRAP --Port Down due to Admin Status down");
    trapMap.put("errorStatus", "0");
    trapMap.put("IPAddress", "10.127.34.219");
```

When we evaluate the expression using MVEL.eval() it either fails or return False. Following is the MVEL expression used and its result.

```
    System.out.println("----------########### = "+(MVEL.eval("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19 == '0'", trapMap)));
    //Throws error as 
    //Exception in thread "main" [Error: invalid number literal: 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19]
    //      [Near : {... 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19 == '0 ....}]

    System.out.println("----------########### = "+(MVEL.eval("\"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19\" == '0'", trapMap)));
    //Enclosed trap OID in double quotes and compared with String value then it returns false

    System.out.println("----------########### = "+(MVEL.eval("\"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19\" == 0", trapMap)));
    //Enclosed trap OID in double quotes and compared with number then it returns false
```

Our Map will always contain such OID and values and we want to validate their values using MVEL. Based on this, we need to know

1. if the expression mentioned is a valid expression if not then what changes are required to make it work.
2. Do we need to add any additional escape characters to the keys mentioned in expression OR
3. This is not possible as the key mentioned in the expression is not valid property/identifier.

Answer (score 1):

`DOT(.)` will create a problem in above expression. `MVEL` internally calls `getter` after each `.` `property`.

we can replace `.` with `_` operator. Also need to add `_` in the starting.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String s = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19 == 0";

        Map<String, String> trapMap = new HashMap();
        trapMap.put(convertDot("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.3"), "(7362915) 20:27:09.15");
        trapMap.put(convertDot("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.2"), "2.2");
        trapMap.put(convertDot("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19"), "0");
        trapMap.put(convertDot("1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.16"), "SIMPLE TRAP --Port Down due to Admin Status down");
        trapMap.put("errorStatus", "0");
        trapMap.put("IPAddress", "10.127.34.219");
        System.out.println(MVEL.eval(convertDot(s), trapMap));

    }

    public static String convertDot(String input) {
        input = "_" + input.replaceAll("\\.", "_");
        return input;
    }
```

**output**

```
true
```

Comment: This means that we need to put keys in Map by following property/identifier naming convention rules as its calling getter calls for the keys.

Comment: @AmitDandavate yes Amit, also MVEL does have meaning for every input (special characters etc.)

Comment: So how many such conversions are needed for each special character? e.g. If I have Key as "trap-data" in the map, which contains special character "-" (hyphen) then also it throws an error saying "[Error: failed to access property: trap: could not access property: trap]". Also is there any doc reference which will give meaning for every special character inputs?

Comment: @Amit Dandavate very little documentation is available on internet. But so far what i have studied and tested, `_` and `$` are not used by MVEL. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Map, you can implicitly call the get method.
The below code will evaluate the correct expression.

```
System.out.println("----------########### = "+(MVEL.eval("get(\"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.311.1.1.2.1.19\") == '0'", trapMap)));
```